# Javascript not recognizing "this" object

Tags: javascript, html, prototype

Please see this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/GSHsH/9/

HTML:

```
<div id="papa" onclick="anything(this);">Blabla</div>​
```

JS:

```
function anything(theObj){
    window.alert(theObj.innerHTML);
}
```

I do not understand why the function "anything" gets as not reconized. (using prototype)

Comment: check the <script> tag if your js file is declared on the page header. if you're using jquery, try window.alert($(theObj).innerHTML);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not that it doesnt recognide `this` - it does not recognise the method `anything` because of a setting you've made in jsfiddle - to scope the javascript into `onLoad`. If you would have chosen `no wrap (head)` it would work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/GSHsH/11/

A bit more detail. The way you set it up, this is what gets injected into the output frame in jsfiddle:

```
Event.observe(window, "load", function(){

function anything(theObj){
    window.alert(theObj.innerHTML);
}

});
```

Note that the method `anything` is not in global (window) scope, it is in the scope of a particular function. This means its not visible to the element on the page.

The way I set it up you get this:

```
function anything(theObj){
    window.alert(theObj.innerHTML);
}
```

Which is just a plain old function defined in the head of the page - now accesible from an element on the page.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me to fix a bigger problem in one of my projects. I called a function using <a href="javascript:thefunction(this)"> and I wasn't able to use the <a> object. Instead the window object was passed.

Comment: Glad to have helped @Octavian

Answer (score 1):

Its because jsfiddle generates your code like this:

```
Event.observe(window, "load", function(){
    function anything (theObj){
        window.alert(theObj.innerHTML);
    }
});
```

so your "anything" function is not in global scope. this will work:

```
window.anything = function (theObj){
    window.alert(theObj.innerHTML);
}
```